# Java JRE 8 install

Tags: software-installation, java, openjdk

I am trying to install Java JRE 8 on my Linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)). I've done two things:

The first was follow [Java's help page](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml#download). I downloaded the tarball and installed it using the `tar zxvf jre-8u73-linux-x64.tar.gz` command. However, when I run:

```
java -version
```

I get: `bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory`

There are no configuration files, and the binary files in `/bin/` are endless... I am not sure which I am supposed to execute. I tried to execute the `java` file, but that did nothing.

So, I tried to just apt-get it. These are the commands I ran:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

However, again, when I run `java -version`, it displays the same thing.

So I said screw it, let me just `mkdir /usr/bin/java` and try it again. I autoremoved the package, and reinstalled it. Now I just get
`bash: /usr/bin/java: Is a directory` when I run `java -version`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: With the command `mkdir /usr/bin/java` you create a directory not an executable, so that's why you get `bash: /usr/bin/java: Is a directory`. Try to remove `/usr/bin/java`, reinstall the package via `ppa` and `apt` and write the output of the command `ls -l /usr/bin/*java*` please.

Comment: When I run that command, I get `ls: cannot access /usr/bin/*java*: No such file or directory`. Interestingly enough, when I run `java -version`, I get a couple of java packages, but not openjdk-8-jre

Comment: I follow this guide since times a go, it's very good: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps. Type "update-aternatives --display java" and you will see which versions of java are installed. So you can uninstall then by command update-alternatives --remove ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other responses for some weird reason did not work for me. So, to install java 1.8 (from Oracle), I alternatively ran this:

1: Add Oracle’s PPA (Personal Package Archive):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

2: Then update your package repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3: Install Oracle JDK 8:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

That got it working for me. Now, when I run `java -version`, I get:

```
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode
```

For more details, see [this post](https://medium.com/coderscorner/installing-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-16-10-845507b13343) on Medium.com.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're not able to install openjdk from the ppa `ppa:openjdk-r/ppa`, maybe it has some problems. But if you want to install the Oracle Java, after you have extracted the folder with `tar zxvf jre-8u73-linux-x64.tar.gz`, you have to make a symbolic link to the executable, try with `sudo ln -sv /path-to-extracted-folder/bin/java /usr/local/bin/java`.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Default JRE/JDK

Firstly you update the package index

```
sudo apt update
```

Next install Java Runtime Environment(JRE) type by

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

And install Java Development Kit (JDk) type by

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Installing the Oracle JDK

Add Oracle's PPA, then update your package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

What version you needed typing in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6/7/8/9-installer
```

After installed Java you Managing your Java version

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Setting the JAVA_HOME Environment Variable

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Copy the path from your preferred installation and then open /etc/environment using nano or your favorite text editor.

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Add a line like this to the file (with the correct path):

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6/7/8/9-oracle"
```

Save and exit the file, and reload it.

```
source /etc/environment
```

You can now test whether the environment variable has been set by executing the following command:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

And type

```
javac --version
java --version
```

These commands display what version of java (the interpreter that runs Java programs) and javac (the compiler that creates them) you have installed.